# how to set char * value from std string (c_str()) not working

Tags: c++, string, pointers

i dont know but this not working for me im getting garbege value when i try to set char * value from function that returns std string :

```
string foo()
{
  string tmp ="dummy value";
  return tmp;
}

char* cc = (char *) foo().c_str(); // if i remove the casting im getting error 
// when i print the cc i get garbage 
printf("%s",cc);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lifetime of the data pointed to by `cc` is the same as the lifetime of the string it came from (at best - if you modify the string it's even shorter).

In your case, the return value of `foo()` is a temporary that is destroyed at the end of the initialization of `cc`.

To avoid the compilation error in `char *cc = foo().c_str()` you shouldn't cast to `char*`, you should switch to `const char *cc`, since `const char*` is what `c_str()` returns. That still doesn't solve the main problem, though.

The simplest fixes are:

```
printf("%s", foo().c_str()); // if you don't need the value again later

const string s = foo();
const char *cc = s.c_str();  // if you really want the pointer - since it's
                             // in the same scope as s, and s is const,
                             // the data lives as long as cc's in scope.

string s = foo();
printf("%s", s.c_str());     // if you don't store the pointer,
                             // you don't have to worry about it.

std::cout << foo(); // printf isn't bringing much to this party anyway.
```

Answer (score 9):

The result of `foo` is a temporary object that gets destroyed by the end of `char * cc = ...` line. Store it in constant reference:

```
const string& cc = foo();
printf ("%s", cc.c_str());
```

Comment: Totally true; `const reference` extending the life of an rvalue happens to be an exotic rule, and 'just' remembering the _value_ would also do.  (Probably optimized with move semantics in C++11).

Comment: Provided that move semantics or RVO are in the works, using value type is pretty much equivalent. But the reference prevents us from relying on compiler optimizations.

Comment: @xtofl: provided the value is stored by using `foo()` as an initializer there's no need for move semantics. Boring old C++03 copy elision will do it.

Comment: +1 for explaining what's wrong with the code and providing the "better world" solution to the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a memory location to foo() and have foo modify that:

```
void foo (string* _out_newStr)
{
    _out_newStr->assign("dummy string"); //This is wrong -> _out_newStr = "dummy string";
    return;
}
```

Then when you are using the "c_str()" function of the string object you will return a const char* value, as already pointed out.

Comment: @Nawaz That's helpful... care to expand? I'm willing to learn also.

Comment: @Dennis: `_out_newStr ` is a pointer to `std::string`, how can you assign character literal to it? Your code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: And even if you change it to `*_out_damned_spot = "dummy string"`, using a single out param in C++ is an attempted optimization that's normally unnecessary. It could well be *slower* than relying on RVO, since the caller has to create an empty string and then you assign to it, whereas with enough copy elision the caller's string can be constructed directly from the literal. Just return by value until proven otherwise.

Comment: @Nawaz: You're right. It didn't. Apologies to the OP. I actually haven't worked with strings in about 3 years due to the age of what I am working on.
I've modified my post.

Comment: @Dennis: Reverted the downvote and upvoted it now. By the way, you could use reference also : `void foo(string & s) {   s  = "dummy string"; }` . This is fine now.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks. You didn't need to but I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The code-snippet invokes undefined behavior, because the temporary `std::string` created from the call is destroyed at the end of the expression but `cc` which is pointing to the destroyed object, is still used even after that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
printf("%s", foo.c_str() );
```

Or better still, forget about using character pointers.

Comment: How about `std::cout << foo()`. :D